# Why can’t UnitType be inferred in > operator?

Tags: swift, generics, types, measurement

Why can’t `UnitType` be inferred in > operator?

```
import Foundation
let mass = Measurement(value: 50, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)
mass > Measurement(value: 100, unit: .kilograms)
```

> Type 'Unit' has no member 'kilograms'

The definition of the operator implies it should:

```
static func > (Measurement<UnitType>, Measurement<UnitType>) -> Bool
```

Comment: The error you’re getting `Type ‘Unit’ has no member ‘kilograms’` doesn’t seem to have anything to do with the > func

Comment: Did you mean to say `mass > Measurement...` instead of `weight > Measurement...`? If not, what is `weight`?

Comment: If you meant to say `mass > Measurement...`, then this works for some reason: `mass > .init(value: 100, unit: .kilograms)`

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler I was about to post this

Comment: @LeoDabus Haha, sorry, I beat you to it! Go ahead and post an answer I guess? I'm not really sure _why_ it works, but `Measurement(value:...` doesn't.

Comment: this is because `Measurement` can be used to initialize any Unit type `.init` assumes the `lhs` type `init(value: Double, unit: UnitMass)`

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler as you said you beat me to it. Go ahead and post the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue there is that `Measurement` is a generic type so you need to specify the Unit type when initializing a new object. If you would like the type to be inferred you need to use `.init` initializer which would infer the UnitMass type `init(value: Double, unit: UnitMass)`:

```
mass > .init(value: 100, unit: .kilograms)
```

Comment: Interesting. Then why is the UnitType inferred here: `let mass: Measurement<UnitMass> = Measurement(value: 50, unit: .kilograms)`? The compiler knows I want to assign a `Measurement<UnitMass>`, because I specified it on the lefthand side. Likewise the compiler should know this in the comparison in my question as it knows that `mass` is `Measurement<UnitMass>`.

Comment: I don’t know how the type inference works under the hood, but you might report it as a bug to Apple and see what they say about it. in my opinion it should work both ways.

Comment: Probable answer would be to close the ticket without a comment ;) …might try that anyways. Thanks a lot!